# XSLT copy-of not working in Opera, breaks tags

Tags: html, xslt, tags, opera

I have problems with Opera splitting my `p` tags where it shouldn't.

Here's the example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="temp.xsl"?>
<data>
    <item name="car">
        <summary>It goes by land.</summary>
    </item>
    <item name="plane">
        <summary>It simply flies.</summary>
    </item>
</data>
```

Here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/data">
        <html>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css"/>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <h1><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h1>
                    <xsl:if test="count(summary)&gt;0">
                        <p class="summary"><xsl:copy-of select="summary" /></p>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the CSS:

```
body { 
    font-size:14px;  text-align:center;  width:400px;  margin:0 auto; font-family:Verdana; 
}

h1 { 
    color: #231F20;  font-size: 1.2em; 
} 

.summary { 
    text-align: justify; padding: 1em; background-color: #F0F4F8;
    border-left: 1px solid #BBB; border-right: 1px solid #BBB; 
}
```

When I run this in IE9 it looks like this:
[image: IE9]

IE9 did not respect body's width, but that is not important, the XSLT transformed the data correctly. The `summary` xml tag is placed between the `p` tag with `class="summary"`.

But when I run this in Opera 12, I get this: [image: Opera12]

As you can see, the width is respected, but the `p` tag was split in two, with `summary` tag inserted between. This can be seen in Opera's inspector:

[image: Inspector]

I need to use `copy-of` instead of `value-of`, because I am expecting the `&lt;summary&gt;` tag to contain the `html` tags like `b`, `i`, or `span`.

Why does Opera break the `p` tag into two empty tags and inserts the `summary` between them? And how to avoid this, enabling me to put the contents of the `summary` tag inside the `p` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well HTML5 has a `summary` element: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-summary-element. It is not clear whether you consider your `summary` element in your input to be an HTML5 `summary` element you want to copy to the result document of your transformation or whether it is simply an arbitrary XML element in your choosen XML input format. As for the differences in parsing in IE and Opera, that might be caused by different HTML5 support in terms of the `summary` element itself or a different HTML5 parsing implementation where Opera seems to treat the summary result element as a HTML5 element and seems to try to move it somewhere where it belongs. As you see in the linked HTML5 specification, it says about the HTML5 `summary` element: "Contexts in which this element can be used: As the first child of a details element.". That means it has no place in a `p` element and because of that it is likely moved outside of the `p` your XSLT tries to place it in.

So you have two choices, either simply copy only the child nodes of your `summary` element, [as you have already done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13082107/93770), or change your XSLT to create clean HTML5 with a `summary` in the right context HTML5 specifies for that element.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't look too deeply into HTML5 so I never thought about new tags. It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that changing the

```
<p class="summary"><xsl:copy-of select="summary" /></p>
```

into

```
<p class="summary"><xsl:copy-of select="summary/node()" /></p>
```

solves the problem.

But I am not sure why the difference across the browsers.